# How to cache duplicate queries in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have some extensive queries (each of them lasts around 90 seconds). The good news is that my queries are not changed a lot. As a result, most of my queries are duplicate. I am looking for a way to cache the query result in PostgreSQL. I have searched for the answer but I could not find it (Some answers are outdated and some of them are not clear).

- I use an application which is connected to the Postgres directly.
- The query is a simple SQL query which return thousands of data instance.

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE field_a<100
```

Is there any way to cache a query result for at least a couple of hours?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to cache expensive queries in postgres using a technique called a "materialized view", however given how simple your query is I'm not sure that this will give you much gain.

You may be better caching this information directly in your application, in memory. Or if possible caching a further processed set of data, rather than the raw rows.

ref:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html

Comment: I am connected to the Postgres through Grafana (a time series admin panel application). So, I am not able to cache the query in the application.

Comment: Normally, in a similar situation I cache the queries using Redis but in this case I am not able to do so.

Comment: What do your rows look like?

Comment: You may wish to consider ETLing the data from postgres into something like https://www.influxdata.com/ if it is high frequency time series data that you wish to display in grafana.

Alternatively consider if you can use the materialized view approach to aggregate the data in some way, such that less rows will need to be returned

Comment: I use influxdb for my time series data. The data stored in the Postgres are not time series but need them represent some visualization.

Comment: Does your grafana widget run aggregate functions over the data? If so, you could probably move the aggregations into postgres onto a materialised view. Can't really offer any better suggestions without more context about what the data looks like and what you are trying to do with it

Comment: No, there is no aggregation in the mentioned query. Now, I think the best solution is to save the result of the query in a separate table and query to that table because there are about 20 queries which take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your application looks like, a [TEMPORARY TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html) might work for you. It is only visible to the connection that created it and it is automatically dropped when the database session is closed.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempfoo AS
  SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE field_a<100;
```

The downside to this approach is that you get a snapshot of `Foo` when you create `tempfoo`. You will not see any new data that gets added to `Foo` when you look at `tempfoo`.

Another approach. If you have access to the database, you may be able to significantly speed up your queries by adding and index on on `field`

Comment: I am using Grafana and in my dashboard I have a raw query (string of the query) which is called. I believe temporary table is not the solution of my problem. I am looking for something like Redis caching but I would like to my Postgres handle it.